# Can't Build aspnetcore app in VS 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

After installing the new VS 2017 RC I'm having issues with building my asnetcore app, here is the error that I am receiving:

> MSB4131   The "FilesWritten" parameter is not supported by the
>   "GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles" task. Verify the parameter exists
>   on the task, and it is a gettable public instance property.

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-HobbyQuarters.Web-e309acfb-31ce-4333-a350-edb5d1c073d3</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader" Version="14.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy">
      <Version>2.0.0-barneyrubble</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Tasks\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: looks like a SDK issue https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this was related to having multiple projects with different msbuild tools versions.

I had older projects that weren't using the new convention of referencing the tools:  ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"...

Once I changed them to use this convention everything started to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch Task Manager
2. end all existing MSBuild tasks.
3. Rebuild your project(s). it should work just fine.

Beside. your .csproj looks just fine to me; however, it looks like its setup to run in two different environment perhaps console and aspcore 1.0